# Bayesian Approach in Ensemble modeling

Tags: bayesian, ensemble-learning

Is ensemble modeling a Bayesian approach? I am thinking it like this:  our final model(posterior) is based on other primary models(prior). Can you guys give your opinions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>The question is probably better suited on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), but I'll give you a hint.</sup>

The way you describe it, Bayesian approach *does not* fit directly, because [Bayes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem) states that posterior equals prior *times* the likelihood (normalized). The final ensemble model is a *weighted sum* of individual models. It's not clear what you consider a likelihood to make an ensemble Bayesian.

If you are looking for a probabilistic interpretation, here's a better one: the ensemble model represents a *joint distribution* of the model selector variable (what is the probability that a particular model is good for a given input) and the model distribution (the accuracy of a particular model). The better you pick both of these distributions (proper models and their weights), the better the ensemble.